# window.execScript fails in ie8

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I work in ruby on rails (3.2.11) with jquery 1.9.1... in my app I developed a chat in javascript.

With IE9 all is ok, in IE8 when calling

```
function refresh_contacts() {       
 url = $('#refresh_contacts_url').val()
 $.ajax(url)
}
```

I get the error in the subject... I tried to isolate the problem and it seems it's the ajax call (just the call, even if there is no code on the called function, so I think it's the call itself who raise the problem)...

The code which raise the error (as indicated by the IE debugger) is in jquery (around line 603 non minified, version 1.9.1):

```
globalEval: function( data ) {
    if ( data && jQuery.trim( data ) ) {
        // We use execScript on Internet Explorer
        // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
        // rather than jQuery in Firefox
        ( window.execScript || function( data ) {
            window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );
        } )( data );
    }
},
```

I tried several workarounds I found on the net like using async: false and cheating with the XMLHttpRequest, with no luck...

Tnx,
Fabio

Comment: addendum: I traced the error in the window.execScript call in ie8, I changed the title of the post accordingly...

Comment: SOLVED!!! in the function called by the execScript there was an assignement without the var, added the var and now it works! damn ie8!!! hope this helps someone else...

Comment: you should set your solution as an answer post instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem is located in a code instructions called by the `window[ "eval" ].call( window, data )`.

The best way to solve this problem is to use Developer Tools in Edge or IE and place a breakpoint on the line with a call. Then You'll be able to see, what's inside the *data* variable. Copy the contents of *data* and put it into some js validator (for example [esprima validator](https://esprima.org/demo/validate.html)). It should display problematic lines for IE. Then correct Your code and You're ready to go!